# Running Apereo CAS on win 10

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas, apereo

I've just built and ran CAS init. According to below guide and I can see UI at localhost:8080/ui. But now I don't know what should I do for next steps to implement a SSO server. I am new to this subject. I have installed JDK 11, Apache Tomcat and running CAS init, on Win 10.

I used these commands respectively:

```
gradlew clean build
gradlew bootRun
```

Running froze at 96%, but I can access localhost:8080 and its UI. I don't know why it's freezing.

After that I tried `curl $INITIALIZR_URL/starter.zip -o cas.zip` but I don't know what to do next.

All I've done is from below guide:

https://github.com/apereo/cas-initializr

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "freezing". Isn't it just that the Initializr app is running in the terminal and waiting to be stopped by ctrl-c?

Answer (score 0):

> after that i tried curl $INITIALIZR_URL/starter.zip -o cas.zip but idk what to do next.

This means you've got a CAS WAR Overlay project stored in the generated `cas.zip` file. All you need to do now is to:

1. Unpack the `cas.zip` file to a folder of your choice.
2. For building and running the resulting CAS application, follow the instructions in the extracted `README.md` file. In essence, you can try to do for example:

   Build the application (`cas.war`):

   ```
   gradlew clean build
   ```

   Run the built application (provided you chose "Executable" deployment type, which is the default):

   ```
   java -jar build/libs/cas.war
   ```

Regarding the **CAS Initializr** application, you don't actually need to build and run it yourself, provided that it is available at https://casinit.herokuapp.com (or https://casinit.herokuapp.com/ui for a clickable UI).

When generating the overlay project via Initializr, don't forget to choose the desired **version** of CAS (e.g. the latest non-snapshot version can be recommended). Besides others, you can also select additional **modules** (dependencies) which you expect to use in your CAS application (e.g. `support-ldap` for authenticating users against LDAP / AD) - they will be automatically added to the correct place in the generated `build.gradle` file. Then you just need to update corresponding CAS configuration file(s) to setup the behavior of the concrete modules used (e.g. the URL to your LDAP server).

Later on, when you need to add another module, you can either do this by directly modifying the extracted `build.gradle` file by following the [CAS documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/), or use the Initializr once again to generate the correct `build.gradle` and possibly other files for you.